# Do something when someone subscribes?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, stream

I have a broadcast stream of a data stream of an BLE device.

In order to get data out of that stream I need to send data to the device before.

```
Stream<Data> dataStream() {
  sendDataRequestToDevice();
  return _broadcastController.stream;
}
```

Problem with that is that everything is asynchronous, meaning that when the stream is returned it's very likely that the actual event sent from the device is gone already. I am searching for something like:

```
Stream<Data> dataStream() {
  return _broadcastController.stream
    .doOnSubscribe(() => sendDataRequestToDevice()); // stolen from rxjava ;)
}
```

Is there something like this in the default Streaming library without using RxDart or similar. (I just dont wanna use it just for this purpose...)

Answer (score 1):

If you care how many subscribers you have, you probably shouldn't be using a broadcast stream. The underlying idea of a broadcast stream is that it *broadcasts* without knowing (or caring) who is listening.
The `onListen` and `onCancel` callbacks were originally not part of a broadcast controller, and they break the model slightly. They do allow you to known when *nobody* is listening, but that is all.

In a situation like this, I'd make my own stream which records the listens and cancels.

```
class _ListenStream<T> extends Stream<T> {
  final Stream<T> _source;
  final void Function() _onListen; 
  final void Function() _onCancel;
  _ListenStream(this._source, this._onListen, this._onCancel);
  bool get isBroadcastStream => _source.isBroadcastStream;
  StreamSubscription<T> listen(void Function(T) onData, {
    Function onError, void Function() onDone, bool cancelOnError = false}) {
    if (_onListen != null) _onListen();
    return _ListenSubscription<T>(_source.listen(onData, 
        onError: onError, onDone: onDone, cancelOnError: cancelOnError),
        _onCancel);  
  }
}
class _ListenSubscription<T> extends StreamSubscription<T> {
  final _StreamSubscription<T> _source;
  final void Function() _onCancel;

  void onData(void handleData(T data)) { _source.onData(handleData); }
  void onError(Function handleError) { _source.onError(handleError); }
  void onDone(void handleDone()) { _source.onDone(handleDone); }

  void pause([Future resumeSignal]) { _source.pause(resumeSignal); }
  void resume() { _source.resume(); }
  Future<E> asFuture<E>([E defaultValue]) => _source.asFuture<E>(defaultValue);
  bool get isPaused => _source.isPaused;

  Future cancel() {
    var future = _source.cancel();
    if (_onCancel != null) future = future.whenComplete(_onCancel);
    return future;
  }
}
```

Then, instead of providing the original stream, you give your clients the `_ListenStream` wrapper of the original stream, along with the callbacks you want called on listen and cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for `onListen`

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/StreamController/onListen.html

```
_broadcastController.onListen = () {
  _broadcastController.add('foo');
};
```

You can also pass the handler to the constructor https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/StreamController/StreamController.html

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for. The onListen on the constructor is called once, as soon as the first subscriber subscribes.

I need something that is always called, when a subscriber subscribes, not just once.

Comment: That should be called for every time the stream is listened to. I'm pretty sure because I used this myself a few times to immediately pass the last value to new receivers. If it doesn't work it might be related to `broadcast`.

Comment: I know what you're talking about. And no, it's not what I need. These methods (onListen, onCancel) are for starting up and closing the broadcast. Meaning, that if you have 10 subscribers on that broadcast, the onListen method is called once.
When I am doing what you're suggesting (just tried that), then I am overriding these broadcast callbacks, which is not what I want. I just want a callback for whenever someone subscribes to the broadcast. (yes it's propably broadcast related, since these methods are free to use if you're not on a broadcast)

Comment: I don't think there is something else. I'd suggest you ask in https://gitter.im/ReactiveX/rxdart or just post a link to this question. The maintainers of this package are pretty good with streams.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone else searching for a solution:

I don't find this a good solution, but it does the job. Please tell me there's a better solution!

```
Stream<Data> dataStream() {
  return StreamGroup.merge([
        doOnSubscribe(() => sendDataRequestToDevice()),
        _broadcastController.stream
      ]);
}

Stream doOnSubscribe(void onSubscribe()) {
  StreamController controller;
  controller = StreamController(
    onListen: () {
      onSubscribe();
      controller.close();
    },
  );
  return controller.stream;
}
```

Sadly it doesn't do the job for my BLE solution, because of other issues.